# Unable to use conda to install software or update itself?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am trying to use conda to install some bioinformatic software such as cufflinks:

```
conda install -c bioconda cufflinks
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid index file: r/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2
```

And it is the same error for any command using conda, somebody knows how to fix it? it looks like I have to uninstall everything and start from cero.

Comment: I solve it by reinstalling conda following these steps: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux.html

Comment: What is the output of `conda config --show`?

Answer (score 1):

Bioconda requires the conda package manager.

If we have Anaconda installation, by default it is already available in it.

For Bioconda, Python 3 version is recommended.

We need to add the bioconda channel as well as the other channels bioconda depends on.

as

conda config --add channels defaults

conda config --add channels conda-forge

conda config --add channels bioconda

Now try installing

```
       conda install -c bioconda cufflinks
```

[image: Installing Bioconda]

Installation will get completed successfully.

[image: Completed Installatio,n]

Reference : https://bioconda.github.io/